# I'm a traditional snare drummer who has serious issues using my left hand

Tags: practice, physical-limitations, hand-independence, snare-drum, drum-stick

I'm looking for exercises to help with my motor control in my left wrist. Ever since I started heavy lifting on a daily basis at work, my left hand has become tighter and stiffer to the point where I have to use my entire arm while playing rather than just moving my wrist.

I'm not even looking for anything music-related, just anything to help loosen my wrists would be of great help!

Thanks,
Cam.

Comment: Hi Cam. Welcome to Music: P&T! Sorry to hear about your arm. I hope someone will be along soon who's had some similar experience and can give you advice. In the meantime, have you come across Alexander Technique? I've known a couple of musicians who were helped by them. There's information about them at this NHS site that should be useful even if you're not in the UK:  https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/alexander-technique/

Comment: First, I suggest you use an arm brace at work, and find ways of favoring your left arm in your work.  Try to use your left wrist as little as possible in your lifting.  And maybe take a bit of a break from playing while you get this figured out.  Second, look for a physical therapist who specializes in hands.  Finally, get a doctor's appointment with an orthopedist who specializes in hands.  Maybe you just need some special stretches and strengthening exercises -- but maybe there's something more serious going on.  Knowledge is power.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I'll have a look into both! - A brace sounds like a ready good idea :)

Comment: Just to check - have you had some manual handling training at work?

Answer (score 1):

It won't solve the problem entirely but before you practice / play do 10 minutes or so of wrist exercises. A lot of the ones for people with arthritis seem to work well for me.

A quick Google of 'wrist exercises for arthiritis' will come back with some good ones and I would personally recommend [this NHS one](https://www.ouh.nhs.uk/patient-guide/leaflets/files/5320Pwrist.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are sympathetic to alternative medicine but you could visit an osteopath and have them examine your wrist. They would also give you exercises. Hopefully it may be just be temporary. No criticism of you but possibly it could be something wrong with your posture when heavy lifting, such as having your arms in a bad position.

No consolation but RSI is now very common among musicians and it is aggravated by using a computer mouse and also stress.